# How to Pass a value from a method into a xpath locator in locators.json file in Cypress

Tags: javascript, json, xpath, automation, cypress

I am failing to send a value from a method to xpath locator in locators.json file, How can I pass a value from javascript method to json file

locators.json

```
{
  "LoginPage":
   {
     "_Postal_TextField" : "//input[@data-testid='is-postal-input']",        
     "_Postal_Dropdown_List" : "//div[@class='relative']//span/p[text()={text}]"
   }
}
```

Expected xpath during runtime is:
`//div[@data-testid="filter-tag-Location"]/p[text()="Thor"]'`

Method.js

```
click_PostalDropdown(value)
{
  cy.clickElement("xpath",or.LoginPage._Postal_Dropdown_List(value))
}
```

Comment: How are you importing the JSON file? What is `clickElement` doing (I'm fairly certain that's a custom command)? What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the selector to read `//div[@data-testid="filter-tag-Location"]/p[text()="Thor"]` you will need to add the double-quotes around the `value`.

Adding the double-quotes to the selector string would be ok if it's inside a class, but it's problematic if it's a JSON file.

You can do it in the method instead using [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax, for example:

```js
const value = 'Thor'
const pattern = "//div[@class='relative']//span/p[text()={text}]"
const selector = pattern.replace('{text}', `"${value}"`)
expect(selector).to.eq(`//div[@class='relative']//span/p[text()="Thor"]`)
```

In the method:

```js
click_PostalDropdown(value) {
  const selector = or.LoginPage._Postal_Dropdown_List.replace('{text}',`"${value}"`)
  cy.clickElement("xpath", selector)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`_Postal_Dropdown_List` is not a function, it is a static field in the JSON. Instead, you can use string replace to insert your `value` variable.

```js
function click_PostalDropdown(value) {
  cy.clickElement(
    "xpath", 
    or.LoginPage._Postal_Dropdown_List.replace("{text}", value)
  );
}
```